# Why I receive a error message like "int object is not callable"

Tags: python, max

```
numb=[1,2,3,4,5]
resu_lt = max(numb)
print(resu_lt)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I try to use max function to find max number But I get int object is not callable. I tried another notebook it worked but it didn't work in the same book that I have bee practised.

Comment: Which programming language do you use? My guess is that you have some integer variable called `max` that obfuscates the `max` function.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to give a definite answer from the provided information. Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

However, from the information you provided you probably assigned a value to a variable called either `max` or `print` as these are the only two objects you call.

For example:

```
numb=[1,2,3,4,5]
resu_lt = max(numb)
print(resu_lt)
```

executes just fine, while

```
max = 8
numb=[1,2,3,4,5]
resu_lt = max(numb)
print(resu_lt)
```

will give you the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: If it is impossible to give an answer, why did you do so?

Comment: @TimRoberts because he can guess the missing information

Comment: @TimRoberts Because I don't have enough reputation to comment (which would have been preferred and was done by another user after my response). However, I was of the opinion that my answer would provide value to the person asking the question with high probability.